# Some transactions through the contact at the same time

Tags: ethereum, web3js

I send some transactions through the contact at the same time. But block executes one of them because both transactions have the same nonce (which I get from getTransactionCount). How can I fix it?

I use this code every time I create a transaction:

```
var token = web3.eth.contract(config.contract.abi).at(config.contract.address);

var payloadData = token.transfer.getData(address, amount);
gasPrice = web3.eth.gasPrice;
gasPriceHex = web3.toHex(gasPrice);
gasLimitHex = web3.toHex(gaslimit);

console.log('Current gasPrice: ' + gasPrice + ' OR ' + gasPriceHex);

nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(config.account.address);
nonceHex = web3.toHex(nonce);
console.log('nonce (transaction count on fromAccount): ' + nonce + '(' + nonceHex + ')');

var rawTx = {
    nonce: nonceHex,
    gasPrice: gasPriceHex,
    gasLimit: gasLimitHex,
    to: config.contract.address,
    from: config.account.address,
    value: '0x00',
    data: payloadData
};

var tx = new Tx(rawTx);
tx.sign(Buffer.from(config.account.privateKey, 'hex'));
var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function (err, hash) {
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
       console.log(hash);
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show us, what you have tried so far.

Comment: I've added the code to my post.